# how to set the color to excel sheet row in c#

Tags: excel, header

I am reading the excel sheet as well as exporting the read excel. I want to set the Fill (backg color) color to header row of exported excel sheet.I am using C# +asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer: oRange.get_Range("A1","X1").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Orange);